# subsetting columns based on columns containing duplicates

Tags: r, unique

i want to subset 3 columns based on one of the columns which has duplicate ids so that i only get 3 columns which have the unique values

```
structure(list(ID = 1:4, x = c(46L, 47L, 47L, 47L), y = c(5L,
```

6L, 7L, 7L)), .Names = c("ID", "x", "y"), row.names = c(1L, 6L, 
11L, 16L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: i want to return the the 3 columns but when they are not duplicated.

Comment: not so, your formula actually works. i want to return a data frame of the three columns but no duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using duplicated on the data frame method should works:

```
dat[!duplicated(dat),] # (equivalent here to dat[!duplicated(dat$ID),] )
   ID  x y
1   1 46 5
6   2 47 6
11  3 47 7
16  4 47 7
```

Comment: > new_data=data[!duplicated(data$ID),]
> new_data
here is the output: structure(list(ID = 1:4, x = c(46L, 47L, 47L, 47L), y = c(5L, 
6L, 7L, 7L)), .Names = c("ID", "x", "y"), row.names = c(1L, 6L, 
11L, 16L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: Thanks all for the response